# Where to include contact details in math paper

Tags: publications, journals, formatting

I recently submitted a paper to a math journal with standard latex formatting, but they sent an email back saying that the contact details for the corresponding author should be in the document itself. Where exactly does this mean? On the title page next to my name?

Right now it looks like this:

Title

First name Last name

April 14, 2014

Abstract

The rest of the paper then follows
...

References

[1] reference...

Where exactly should I include my email address?
I am the only author of this paper.

Comment: Did the journal provide a template?

Comment: Look at other papers printed by the same journal.

Comment: What does the journal's guide to authors say?

Comment: I doubt it matters where you put the contact information in the submitted version (the journal will reformat it if accepted).  Sometimes it's a footnote on the first page, sometimes it's arranged next to the author's name, and sometimes it's at the end of the paper.  The easiest thing is probably to use the amsart document class, which is common in mathematics and will handle this automatically (it puts it at the end).

Comment: In many templates, ams among them, it is `\author{John Smith} \email{john.smith@mathematics.edu}`

Comment: If they just said "in the document itself" and didn't say where in the document, then I think it's up to you and your software to decide where to put this information. I use amsart which, as Anonymous Mathematician and Davidmh said, gives you easy macros for entering this information and then prints it at the end of the paper.

Answer (score 8):

This depends entirely on the journal's style. They should provide a LaTeX class or template that explicitly identifies how to include the corresponding author's contact info, or if not that, a web page with instructions on how to include contact information. Without knowing which journal you're talking about, I don't think I can say anything more than that.